# Puppet - Grant user SELECT access via puppetlabs/postgresql

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I am having difficulty creating users with read-only access to all tables in a schema.

I am using the following in the manifest

```
  postgresql::server::grant {<Unique friendly name>:
    db          => <dbname>,
    object_name => <schema_name>,
    object_type => 'ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA',
    privilege   => 'SELECT',
    role        => <username>,
  }
```

In the puppet run, I get the following error:
`Could not evaluate: Error evaluating 'unless' clause, returned pid 6933 exit 1: 'ERROR:  unrecognized privilege type: "SELECT ON ALL TABLES"`

Yet looking at the manifest:

```
postgresql::server::grant
Manages grant-based access privileges for roles. See PostgreSQL documentation for grant for more information.

db
Specifies the database to which you are granting access.

object_type
Specifies the type of object to which you are granting privileges. Valid options: DATABASE, SCHEMA, SEQUENCE, ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA, TABLE or ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA.

object_name
Specifies name of object_type to which to grant access.

port
Port to use when connecting. Default: undef, which generally defaults to port 5432 depending on your PostgreSQL packaging.

privilege
Specifies the privilege to grant. Valid options: ALL, ALL PRIVILEGES or object_type dependent string.

psql_db
Specifies the database to execute the grant against. This should not ordinarily be changed from the default, which is postgres.

psql_user
Sets the OS user to run psql. Default: the default user for the module, usually postgres.

role
Specifies the role or user whom you are granting access to.
```

Hunting down the 'privilege type':
`privilege_type='${custom_privilege}'`

```
$custom_privilege = $_privilege ? {
        'ALL'            => 'INSERT',
        'ALL PRIVILEGES' => 'INSERT',
        default          => $_privilege,
      }
```

And finally
`validate_string($_privilege,'SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','TRUNCATE','REFERENCES','TRIGGER','ALL','ALL PRIVILEGES')`

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the source code, my best guess is that something is being incorrectly assigned to `table_name` in the `$custom_unless`.